# How can I call controller/view helper methods from the console in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

When I load `script/console`, sometimes I want to play with the output of a controller or a view helper method.

Are there ways to:

- simulate a request?
- call methods from a controller instance on said request?
- test helper methods, either via said controller instance or another way?

Comment: 100 years later, I still google for this

Answer (score 499, accepted):

To call helpers, use the `helper` object:

```
$ ./script/console
>> helper.number_to_currency('123.45')
=> "R$ 123,45"
```

If you want to use a helper that's not included by default (say, because you removed `helper :all` from `ApplicationController`), just include the helper.

```
>> include BogusHelper
>> helper.bogus
=> "bogus output"
```

As for dealing with **controllers**, I quote [Nick's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151030/how-do-i-call-controller-view-methods-from-the-console-in-rails/1436342#1436342) answer:

> ```
> > app.get '/posts/1'
> > response = app.response
> # you now have a rails response object much like the integration tests
>
> > response.body            # get you the HTML
> > response.cookies         # hash of the cookies
>
> # etc, etc
> ```

Comment: I observe that I can't execute more than one `app.get` (a thread error ensues). Is there a way I can flush the system and execute more gets?

Comment: Note in Rails 3.2 this does not work.  I needed to call `url_for` from the console.  To do this I did `app.url_for(...)`

Comment: For `NoMethodError: undefined method \`protect_against_forgery?' for nil:NilClass` define a function called `protect_against_forgery?` within the console that returns `false`

Comment: how do I set the currently logged in user?

Comment: @RudolfOlah It seems that if you are using device (or warden) you can do it with `ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.include(Warden::Test::Helpers); Warden.test_mode! ; app.login_as(User.find(1), scope: :user)`.

Answer (score 158):

An easy way to call a controller action from a script/console and view/manipulate the response object is:

```
> app.get '/posts/1'
> response = app.response
# You now have a Ruby on Rails response object much like the integration tests

> response.body            # Get you the HTML
> response.cookies         # Hash of the cookies

# etc., etc.
```

The app object is an instance of [ActionController::Integration::Session](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Integration/Session.html)

This works for me using Ruby on Rails 2.1 and 2.3, and I did not try earlier versions.

Comment: A link to official documentation on app object would be good.

Comment: It is an instance of the ActionController::Integration::Session class. I have updated the answer to include that.

Comment: How can I authenticate the console, so I can check controllers that require authentication?

Comment: You should be able to post to your log in page, something like: app.post '/session/new', { :username => "foo", :password => "pass" }. And then continue to use the same "app" variable to get pages after that.

Comment: That link is broken (as it's Rails 2.x). `app` is now an `ActionDispatch::Integration::Session `: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Integration/Session.html. The `get`, `post`, `patch` methods are defined in http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Integration/RequestHelpers.html

Comment: Been working with Rails for two years now, first time I heard of this awesome way to hit controllers!

Answer (score 119):

If you need to test from the console (tested on Ruby on Rails 3.1 and 4.1):

Call Controller Actions:

```
app.get '/'
   app.response
   app.response.headers  # => { "Content-Type"=>"text/html", ... }
   app.response.body     # => "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n\n<head>\n..."
```

ApplicationController methods:

```
foo = ActionController::Base::ApplicationController.new
foo.public_methods(true||false).sort
foo.some_method
```

Route Helpers:

```
app.myresource_path     # => "/myresource"
app.myresource_url      # => "http://www.example.com/myresource"
```

View Helpers:

```
foo = ActionView::Base.new

foo.javascript_include_tag 'myscript' #=> "<script src=\"/javascripts/myscript.js\"></script>"

helper.link_to "foo", "bar" #=> "<a href=\"bar\">foo</a>"

ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag('logo.png')  #=> "<img alt=\"Logo\" src=\"/images/logo.png\" />"
```

Render:

```
views = Rails::Application::Configuration.new(Rails.root).paths["app/views"]
views_helper = ActionView::Base.new views
views_helper.render 'myview/mytemplate'
views_helper.render file: 'myview/_mypartial', locals: {my_var: "display:block;"}
views_helper.assets_prefix  #=> '/assets'
```

ActiveSupport methods:

```
require 'active_support/all'
1.week.ago
=> 2013-08-31 10:07:26 -0300
a = {'a'=>123}
a.symbolize_keys
=> {:a=>123}
```

Lib modules:

```
> require 'my_utils'
 => true
> include MyUtils
 => Object
> MyUtils.say "hi"
evaluate: hi
 => true
```

Comment: This helps when you are writing independent ruby scripts that will be run using rails runner and they need to call methods in application controller. Thanks

Comment: @CodeExpress That should never happen. Instead, put the methods in a service object, and call the service from both ApplicationController and your script.

Answer (score 79):

Here's one way to do this through the console:

```
>> foo = ActionView::Base.new
=> #<ActionView::Base:0x2aaab0ac2af8 @assigns_added=nil, @assigns={}, @helpers=#<ActionView::Base::ProxyModule:0x2aaab0ac2a58>, @controller=nil, @view_paths=[]>

>> foo.extend YourHelperModule
=> #<ActionView::Base:0x2aaab0ac2af8 @assigns_added=nil, @assigns={}, @helpers=#<ActionView::Base::ProxyModule:0x2aaab0ac2a58>, @controller=nil, @view_paths=[]>

>> foo.your_helper_method(args)
=> "<html>created by your helper</html>"
```

Creating a new instance of `ActionView::Base` gives you access to the normal view methods that your helper likely uses.  Then extending `YourHelperModule` mixes its methods into your object letting you view their return values.

Answer (score 18):

If the method is the `POST` method then:

```
app.post 'controller/action?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2'
```

(Here parameters will be as per your applicability.)

Else if it is the `GET` method then:

```
app.get 'controller/action'
```

Comment: And to find paths you want, `app.methods.grep(/_path/)` :)

Comment: And it's not always `controler/action`, depends on your routes, e.g. could be `/users/all` and map to `Api::UsersController#index` :)

Comment: @Dorian Or `rake routes`. :)

Answer (score 16):

Here is how to make an authenticated POST request, using Refinery as an example:

```
# Start Rails console
rails console
# Get the login form
app.get '/community_members/sign_in'
# View the session
app.session.to_hash
# Copy the CSRF token "_csrf_token" and place it in the login request.
# Log in from the console to create a session
app.post '/community_members/login', {"authenticity_token"=>"gT7G17RNFaWUDLC6PJGapwHk/OEyYfI1V8yrlg0lHpM=",  "refinery_user[login]"=>'chloe', 'refinery_user[password]'=>'test'}
# View the session to verify CSRF token is the same
app.session.to_hash
# Copy the CSRF token "_csrf_token" and place it in the request. It's best to edit this in Notepad++
app.post '/refinery/blog/posts', {"authenticity_token"=>"gT7G17RNFaWUDLC6PJGapwHk/OEyYfI1V8yrlg0lHpM=", "switch_locale"=>"en", "post"=>{"title"=>"Test", "homepage"=>"0", "featured"=>"0", "magazine"=>"0", "refinery_category_ids"=>["1282"], "body"=>"Tests do a body good.", "custom_teaser"=>"", "draft"=>"0", "tag_list"=>"", "published_at(1i)"=>"2014", "published_at(2i)"=>"5", "published_at(3i)"=>"27", "published_at(4i)"=>"21", "published_at(5i)"=>"20", "custom_url"=>"", "source_url_title"=>"", "source_url"=>"", "user_id"=>"56", "browser_title"=>"", "meta_description"=>""}, "continue_editing"=>"false", "locale"=>:en}
```

You might find these useful too if you get an error:

```
app.cookies.to_hash
app.flash.to_hash
app.response # long, raw, HTML
```

Comment: `NameError: undefined local variable or method app for main:Object`

Comment: you also need disable forgery_protection `ApplicationController.allow_forgery_protection = false`

Comment: Wow that's probably easier. What I wrote is with forgery protection. You don't need to disable it, but I'm sure it's more convenient!

Answer (score 15):

Another way to do this is to use the Ruby on Rails debugger. There's a Ruby on Rails guide about debugging at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Basically, start the server with the -u option:

```
./script/server -u
```

And then insert a breakpoint into your script where you would like to have access to the controllers, helpers, etc.

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    debugger
  end
end
```

And when you make a request and hit that part in the code, the server console will return a prompt where you can then make requests, view objects, etc. from a command prompt. When finished, just type 'cont' to continue execution. There are also options for extended debugging, but this should at least get you started.

Comment: > => Notice: debugger option is ignored since Ruby 2.0 and it will be removed in future versions.

Answer (score 15):

You can access your methods in the Ruby on Rails console like the following:

```
controller.method_name
helper.method_name
```

Answer (score 9):

In Ruby on Rails 3, try this:

```
session = ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.new(Rails.application)
session.get(url)
body = session.response.body
```

The body will contain the HTML of the URL.

*[How to route and render (dispatch) from a model in Ruby on Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770119/how-to-route-and-render-dispatch-from-a-model-in-rails-3)*

Answer (score 8):

The earlier answers are calling helpers, but the following will help for calling controller methods. I have used this on Ruby on Rails 2.3.2.

First add the following code to your .irbrc file (which can be in your home directory)

```
class Object
   def request(options = {})
     url=app.url_for(options)
     app.get(url)
     puts app.html_document.root.to_s
  end
end
```

Then in the Ruby on Rails console you can type something like...

```
request(:controller => :show, :action => :show_frontpage)
```

...and the HTML will be dumped to the console.

Answer (score 5):

For controllers, you can instantiate a controller object in the Ruby on Rails console.

For example,

```
class CustomPagesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @customs = CustomPage.all
  end

  def get_number
    puts "Got the Number"
  end

  protected

  def get_private_number
    puts 'Got private Number'
  end

end

custom = CustomPagesController.new
2.1.5 :011 > custom = CustomPagesController.new
 => #<CustomPagesController:0xb594f77c @_action_has_layout=true, @_routes=nil, @_headers={"Content-Type"=>"text/html"}, @_status=200, @_request=nil, @_response=nil>
2.1.5 :014 > custom.get_number
Got the Number
 => nil

# For calling private or protected methods,
2.1.5 :048 > custom.send(:get_private_number)
Got private Number
 => nil
```

Comment: It works! But how can I update action variables. Ex:

`def show
    response = @user.contributions
end
`

How do I override the `@user` variable?

Answer (score 4):

Inside any controller action or view, you can invoke the console by calling the **console** method.

For example, in a controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    console
    @post = Post.new
  end
end
```

Or in a view:

```
<% console %>

<h2>New Post</h2>
```

This will render a console inside your view. You don't need to care about the location of the console call; it won't be rendered on the spot of its invocation but next to your HTML content.

See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Answer (score 3):

One possible approach for Helper method testing in the Ruby on Rails console is:

```
Struct.new(:t).extend(YourHelper).your_method(*arg)
```

And for reload do:

```
reload!; Struct.new(:t).extend(YourHelper).your_method(*arg)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have added your own helper and you want its methods to be available in console, do:

1. In the console execute `include YourHelperName`
2. Your helper methods are now available in console, and use them calling `method_name(args)` in the console.

Example: say you have MyHelper (with a method `my_method`) in 'app/helpers/my_helper.rb`, then in the console do:

1. `include MyHelper`
2. `my_helper.my_method`

Answer (score 1):

Trying to edit [Tbabs' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15709071/1713808), but on second thought, better add an answer.

Like the most upvoted answer said, the `app` method is available in the console.
[A handful of examples are there.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9159853/1713808)

I want to point out that the official API doc has mentioned the functionalities here: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/ConsoleMethods.html

By reading the doc, you will discover that there is also the `new_session` method that you might prefer over `app` for the use case.