# How do I generate a view from the console/script-runner in merb?

Tags: ruby, model-view-controller, view, merb

I'd like to generate a lot of merb views (around 350.000) and save them to separate files programmatically (they will actually be XML files). One option would be to simply `wget` them, but that is too slow (already tried it, but takes around two days). For rails I've already found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151030/how-do-i-call-controller-view-methods-from-the-console-in-rails/1436342#1436342) but that doesn't work with merb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually the same as for the answer for rails, but you have to substitute `app` with `merb`