# I thought Ruby on Rails "script/console" can let me do "render :text => 'hello' " but it says render is not defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I thought Ruby on Rails "script/console" can let me do "render :text => 'hello' " but it says render is not defined?

Answer (score 7):

Call `render` via `helper`:

```
>> helper.render :text => "foo"
=> "foo"
```

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151030/how-do-i-call-controller-view-methods-from-the-console-in-rails).

Comment: `helper.number_to_currency('123.45')` works, but `helper.render :text => "foo"` doesn't

Comment: What version of `Rails` are you using? I tested it with `2.3.4` and `3beta3` check out this gist. http://gist.github.com/499498

Comment: I am using 2.2.2 in our dev / prod environment