# Rails calling a controller action from the console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I have a controller sessions that can create session.
I'd like to call it from the console, like controller.create.
Here is the action:

```
  def create  
    #raise request.env["omniauth.auth"].to_yaml

    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]  
    user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"]) || User.create_with_omniauth(auth)  
    user.create_or_update_profile(auth)
    session[:user_id] = user.id 

    if user.needs_to_create_profile?
      redirect_to new_profile_path, :notice => "Signed in!. We just need your contact e-mail"
    else
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed in!"  
    end
  end
```

Comment: Answered/Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151030/how-do-i-call-controller-view-methods-from-the-console-in-rails/1161163#1161163

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151030/how-do-i-call-controller-view-methods-from-the-console-in-rails

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the console:

```
   include ActionController::TestProcess
   @request = ActionController::TestRequest.new
   @response = ActionController::TestResponse.new
   @controller = SomeController.new

   @request.env["omniauth.auth"] = {'provider' => "twitter", 'uid' => "1234", 'user_info' => {'name' => "foo"}}

   app.get "/signup" etc
```

From rspec:

```
it "should allow login" do
    request.env["omniauth.auth"] = {'provider' => "twitter", 'uid' => "1234", 'user_info' => {'name' => "foo"}}
    post :create
    puts @current_user.name
    assigns(@current_user).should_not be_nil
  end
```

Comment: `ActionController::TestProcess` is not present on rails 4.