# How can I run a Controller Action from Rails Console, but setting the request.shot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing, rails-console

I'm working on a multi-tenant application, so pretty much everything throughout (starting with routing) expects to have a "request.host" that looks like "tenant_id.myapp.com".

I'm trying to run a controller action from the Rails console, but I haven't been able to figure this one out.

The easiest thing to do seems to be "app.get", but I can't figure out how to set the host.

I also saw [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4403462/3314) that mentions using "ActionController::TestProcess", which as far as I understand has been removed from Rails (or if not, I haven't found how to include it)

Any other options?

Thanks!
Daniel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just verified it in my console(Pry)

```
# Send request with fake HTTP_HOST
>>app.get(app.root_path, nil, {"HTTP_HOST" => "123.myapp.com"})
>>#=>200

# Then check if it works
>>app.request.env
>>#...
>># "HTTP_HOST" : "123.myapp.com"
```

Comment: My pleasure! The doc of `get` is here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Integration/RequestHelpers.html#method-i-get It is not removed, just changed place.