# How do I render a partial from the Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails 4.0.3. How do I render a partial from the Rails console?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I call controller/view methods from the console in Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151030/how-do-i-call-controller-view-methods-from-the-console-in-rails)

Comment: Check out this previous SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538798/rendering-a-partial-from-a-ruby-script-or-console

Comment: @GraemeMcLean None of those answers are about `#render`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try this (in the console):

```
# initial setup
view_paths = Rails::Application::Configuration.new(Rails.root).paths["app/views"]
av_helper = ActionView::Base.new view_paths

# (Optional) include this if your partial uses route helpers:
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

av_helper.render "path/to/your/partial"
```

Also, for templates:

```
av_helper.render :template => "path/to/your/template"
```

**Update:** The OP reported the partial rendering line did not work, and generated an error. I didn't encounter that, but if others do, this is the version the OP indicated was successful:

```
av_helper.render :partial => 'tags/tag', :collection => Tag.limit(3)
```

As Josh Diehl pointed out, you can also use the usual options like `locals` in the render. I would expect you should be able to use all the usual render options normally used in controllers and views.

Josh's example:

```
av_helper.render(partial: "tags/tag", locals: {term: term})
```

Comment: With locals: `av_helper.render(partial: "tags/tag", locals: {term: term})`

Comment: Cool, thanks @JoshDiehl, makes sense. I would expect all the usual render options to work. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Any way to make instance variables available as are commonly used in Rails views?

Comment: @justingordon I don't know why I didn't catch your question earlier, sorry for the delay. You could pass them via the `locals` key like described above; you can convert your object's instance variables to a hash like described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8417341/877472), which is similar to how [Rails passes controller instance variables](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18855824/877472).

Answer (score 30):

There is an official way to do this in Rails 5 (cf [this pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18409)):

`ApplicationController.render 'templates/name'`

The developer also made a gem to support this in Rails 4: [backport_new_renderer](https://github.com/brainopia/backport_new_renderer)

Answer (score 13):

For me the best way to get it working in Rails 4.2 was with this twoliner:

```
view = ActionView::Base.new('app/views/products', {},  ActionController::Base.new)
output = view.render(file: 'index.html', locals: {:@products => Product.all})
```

I found this solution [on github.](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11662#issuecomment-44366029)