# Calling an ApplicationController method from console in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails, supposing that the file is already loaded, how it is possible to call `my_method`  from this example from console?

```
# some_file.rb
class MyClass < ApplicationController::Base
  def my_method(args)
```

Comment: That actually sounds interesting.But my first thought would be that all methods inside controllers are accessed by the views.When you access the console, you're accessing ActiveRecord and get access to your models and their methods.As I said,that would be my first thought.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/151030/2355112 has really good answers regarding the same issue.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Another, very simple way to do this is to use an instance of `ApplicationController` itself.

```
ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def example
    "O HAI"
  end
end
```

Then in the console, you can do the following:

```
>> ApplicationController.new.example
```

This will output the following:

```
O HAI
```

This, of course, has the restriction of not having access to everything a normal request would, such as the `request` object itself. If you need this, as the Patrick Klingemann suggested, you could use the debugger... I personally recommend using Pry:

- [Pry on RubyGems.org](http://rubygems.org/gems/pry)
- [RailsCast: Pry with Rails](http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails)

This is likely much too late for you, but hopefully it will help someone in the future.

Comment: very good solutions, Help for writing view, and controller test cases.

Answer (score 3):

use debugger:

in your `Gemfile` add:

```
gem 'debugger'
```

then from the terminal:

```
> bundle
> rails s --debugger
```

in the controller action you're hitting:

```
class WidgetsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    debugger
    @widgets = Widget.all
    respond_with @widgets
  end
end
```

then point your browser to: `http://localhost:3000/widgets`, the page will not finish loading.  Return to the terminal where your server is running and you'll be in an interactive debugging session where you can run: `my_method`

Comment: I actually forgot about debugging.Still notice that you won't get access to the method launching your server like that. You'd need to: rails s --debugger.And even in that case the only response you get is "Just hit an ApplicationController method"... no actual output

Comment: I thought of the --debugger as I went to sleep, good point.  I'm not sure I understand the second sentence in your comment.

Comment: well I tried reproducing the case Martin set up for us but what I get is that message...I mean I can't actually check what's going on inside the method when I call it.I might be doing something wrong though...

Comment: (Displaimer: This is only my opinion.) debugger is dead, man. Give [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) a shot!

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly the question asked, but you can also debug with the `pry` gem, similarly to `debugger`.

Add to the `Gemfile`:

```
gem "pry"
gem "pry-remote"
gem "pry-stack_explorer"
gem "pry-debugger"
```

In your method:

```
def myMethod
  binding.pry
  # some code
end
```

Done!

When you run your method, the page processing will freeze at `binding.pry` and pry will take over the prompt. Type `n` for each new step of the method, and play around with your variables that can be print (just typing them) in "real-time"!