# Why do date helpers not work in Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a datetime attribute on a record:

```
 1.9.3p194 :024> f.last_contact
 => Thu, 11 Aug 2011 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
```

But when I try `time_ago_in_words` at the console, it doesn't work:

```
> time_ago_in_words(f.last_contact)
NoMethodError: undefined method `time_ago_in_words' for main:Object
```

I also tried `distance_of_time_in_words` which the docs say should work with [Time, Date & DateTime objects](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words).

```
> to_time = Time.now
 => 2012-09-08 12:22:16 -0500 
> distance_of_time_in_words(f.last_contact, to_time)
NoMethodError: undefined method `distance_of_time_in_words' for main:Object
```

What is the cause of this? Shouldn't Rails Console load all the necessary libraries and dependencies for all of Rails methods to work?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can use all helpers (built-in and your own) through `helper` object

```
helper.time_ago_in_words(1.hour.ago)
=> "about 1 hour"
```

Or import required helpers

```
include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper
time_ago_in_words(1.hour.ago)
=> "about 1 hour"
```

Comment: How can that be used in this scenario: `@user.current_sign_in_at.time_ago_in_words` (in the view)?

Comment: For some reason having "helpers" instead of "helper" helped me

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
helper.time_ago_in_words(...)
helper.distance_of_time_in_words(...)
```

Calling `helper.` seems to give you access to any/all defined helpers.

More info in this answer: [How do I call controller/view methods from the console in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151030/how-do-i-call-controller-view-methods-from-the-console-in-rails)

The reason, I think, that you can't just call the helper directly is because they're not in scope from where you are (in the console), as opposed to code that's running inside a view where the helpers are in scope.