# Is there a time ahead words in rails (opposite of time_ago_in_words)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

Is there a rails helper opposite of time_ago_in_words ? I can't seem to find the opposite...where I can have 7 days from now converted to "in about 1 week". 
I can get this to work for the past:

```
 <%= time_ago_in_words( milestone.due_date) %>
```

But this doesn't work for the future:

```
   <%= time_ahead_in_words(milestone.due_date) %>
```

stumped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`distance_of_time_in_words(from_time, to_time = 0, options = {})`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/distance_of_time_in_words) instead.

So you could set it up like so:

`<%= distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now, milestone.due_date) %>`

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're in need of the "distance_in_time" helper method.

Ex.

```
    from_time = Time.current
helper.distance_of_time_in_words(from_time, from_time + 50.minutes)

=>about 1 hour
```

More specifically, in your case you would do:

```
from_time = Time.current
    helper.distance_of_time_in_words(from_time, from_time + 6.days)

    =>about 7 days
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `distance_of_time_in_words`. For example:

```
distance_of_time_in_words(Time.current, milestone.due_date)
```

would be equivalent to your `time_ahead_in_words` pseudo code.

See [distance_of_time_in_words documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words) for details.

Answer (score 0):

`distance_of_time_in_words` is what you're after. Be aware that:

1. `distance_of_time_in_words` doesn't ***assume*** you mean ***from now***, so you have to tell it that with `Time.current`. E.g.

```rb
appointment_start_time = ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Sydney'].parse("2022-11-14 07:00:00 UTC")
distance_of_time_in_words(Time.current, appointment_start_time)
=> "about 2 years"
```

2. `distance_of_time_in_words` will still return a result if the time was in the past, so beware of that!
3. if using `distance_of_time_in_words` in the rails console, [you need to prepend `helper.`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12333009/5783745), like so:

```rb
helper.distance_of_time_in_words(Time.current, appointment_start_time)
=> "about 2 years"
```

References:

- [docs for `distance_of_time_in_words`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words)
- [ActiveSupport TimeZones and their aliases](https://gist.github.com/eikes/5a64b661022c756bd6522ed94770e2a6)