# Discrepancies in function calls in ruby server and ruby console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

New to ruby, trying to figure out how to debug this problem - I've been working on a search method, and the search call returns correctly on the server, but not the console.

```
Item.where() { has_keyword "phone" }
```

returns [] on the server, returns a list with 15 objects on the console. What kinds of differences exist between the server and console? Where should I start looking?

Comment: make sure each is using the same environment. `Rails.env` should both be development or production

Comment: Check the database name in both development and production. It should be same..

Comment: @JesseWolgamott: the Rails.env variables are both "development". Any other ideas? (Thanks for the suggestions!)

Answer (score 0):

is "has_keyword" a function inside of your app or a function that is native to rails? If you have written that function yourself you may need to include the file before you can access the function from rails.

[How do I call controller/view methods from the console in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151030/how-do-i-call-controller-view-methods-from-the-console-in-rails)

My advise would be to write the function as a model scope so you can then access it by saying something like `Item.has_keyword("Phone")`

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes