# Save rendered static html, css, javascript files locally from Ruby on Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How would you save Ruby on Rails rendered page into static page with html, css, javascript files locally?

[I initially wanted to use using `wget` command within Rails, but it failed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465101/using-wget-on-rails-server-itself)

There also seems to be a lot of threads making use of `render_to_string`, but this only deals with HTML of the static page. It doesn't help in saving css and javascript.

Comment: I guess `File > Save Page` from your browser is not sufficient?

Comment: Are you trying to cache completely static pages? If so this would be hangdled by your server. If you are trying to cache Rails data + HTML/CSS/JS, then you try looking at the Rails Caching Guide, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html. Or maybe you are thinking of something else?

Comment: No, File > Save Page is not sufficient because I have to be able to do this for thousands of pages.

Comment: No, I am not caching. I want to save static pages locally.

Comment: did you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

**app.get URL** on **rails console** is what you have been looking...
([How do I call controller/view methods from the console in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151030/how-do-i-call-controller-view-methods-from-the-console-in-rails))