# Rails 4 strong parameters failing when creating instances in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

Probably doing something stupid here, but here's my basic cookie cutter class:

```
class League < ActiveRecord::Base

    private
      def league_params
        params.require(:full_name).permit!
      end

end
```

And when creating a new instance of League:

```
2.0.0-p0 :001 > l = League.new(full_name: 'foo', short_name: 'bar')
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for League: full_name, short_name
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here? This is a Rails 4.0.0.beta1 build + Ruby 2.0

** UPDATE **

I realize now that strong parameters are enforced in the Controller now and not in the model. The original question still stands. If they are permitted on the controller level, how can I properly whitelist attributes if I'm creating instances in the Rails console? Wouldn't I need to also use `attr_accessible` in this case also thereby completely duplicating what strong parameters is trying to "fix"?

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile? Also the code in your model?

Comment: @randombits did you upgrade your project from rails3 ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Two things. The `league_params` definition goes in the controller, not the model. And `params.require()` should contain the name of the model that is required to be present in the parameters, not the attributes. The attribute presence check should still be in the model validations. And be sure you really want to allow access to all attributes in the League model before you use `permit!`. So, it should look like this:

```
class LeaguesController < ApplicationController

  private
    def league_params
      params.require(:league).permit!
    end

end
```

Update:

Yes, if you want the attributes to be restricted when accessing the model directly, you would need to switch back to using the `attr_accessible` in the model. That functionality has been moved into this gem: https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes.

I think it is assumed that if you are working with the model directly in the console, you don't need the attributes to be protected as you know exactly what is being entered. As the console has full access to your app, it would be just as easy to hose the entire database as it would be to maliciously assign an attribute.

Comment: What if League is not getting created in the controller? I'm creating it in the console in this particular case.

Comment: Then you don't need to use permitted params. Permitted params is used to protect against data entered by the user.

Comment: so then I need to resort back to attr_accessible anyway?

Answer (score 7):

The basic security reason for the existence of both **strong parameters** and **attr_accessible** is that there are certain attributes in the model that should not be allow to be changed unless it is the explicit intention of your code.

The slight difference between them is the perspective form which they do their jobs.

**StrongParameters** focus on the use case: each controller's action can be fine tuned to allow or disallow certain parameters, taking in consideration any condition. Total flexibility.

**attr_accessible** takes a different perspective. Instead of focusing on the use case, it focus on roles. So for example, depending on the role of the user certain attributes can be changed or not.

---

The way to use **StrongParameters** is to apply the `require` and `permit` keywords on the param hash.

`require` states that a key must be present on the params hash. `require` will raise an exception if there is not such a key.

`permit` states that a field is allowed. Any key that is not allowed will be removed from the hash and hence will not be passed to the model by means of mass-assignment.

Model

```
class League
   attr_protected :final_price  # Nobody can mass-assign the final price
   attr_accessible :winner_name, :as => :jury
end
```

And the controller

```
class LeaguesController < ApplicationController
```

These two actions use **StrongParameters**

```
  # A common user can create a league
  def create
    league = League.new(league_params)
    league.final_price = 1000
    league.save
    redirect_to(league)
  end

  # But only the admin can publish a league
  def publish_league
     league = League.find(params[:id]
     league.update_attributes(league_params_as_admin)
  end
```

This one uses **attr_accessible**

```
  def publish_the_winner
    league = League.find(params[:id]
    # We would expect the current_user.role to return :jury.
    league.assign_attributes(params[:league], :as => current_user.role)
  end

  private
    def league_params
      params.require(:league).permit(:name)
    end

    def league_params_as_admin
      params.require(:league).permit(:name, :status)
    end 

end
```

In my experience:

Use the flexibility of Strong Parameters to fine tune what attributes can be mass-assigned in each of your controllers.

Use the omnipresence of attr_accesible to make sure that certain attributes can not be mass-assigned no matter what. For example, in a Resque Task you may pass user input as a parameter. You would check that some attributes are not mass-assigned using attr_accesible.

More info:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html

https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters

Answer (score 1):

It seems the whitelisting is active, even though you are running Rails 4. Did you upgrade to Rails 4 from a Rails 3 app? Do you have this in your `config/application.rb`?

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
```

Double-check that strong parameters are in force on all your models. If they are, you can change this setting to `false`.

Also, double-check that there is no `attr_accessible` in your model.

Comment: I'm not the author of the topic, but thanks. When I upgraded my project from Rails3 to Rails4, this message was shown. But if I create Rails 4 project with the same code (even in configs), message won't shown. I don't know why, seems like a small bug.

Comment: It is not possible to upgrade this transparently, developer assistance is needed. I believe the original poster must have added the `protected_attributes` gem, otherwise there would have been an error. (Perhaps the error tells you to install that gem, I do not have the right computer in front of me to check). The best way to upgrade to Rails 4 is to first use the strong_parameters gem and go through all controllers and models to work in the new way, only after that upgrading the Rails gem.

Comment: Is the config in your Rails 4 project really the same? I'm guessing the mentioned config line is missing or set to false.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling your models directly, then yes it will sidestep any logic you have implemented in your controllers.

You can however call your controllers from the console, then the StrongParameters implemented there will take effect.

see [How do I call controller/view methods from the console in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151030/how-do-i-call-controller-view-methods-from-the-console-in-rails)