# Upgrading Rails 3.2 to Rails 4 and Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I was upgrading my project from Rails3 to Rails4 with this tutorial: [RailsCasts](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEEQtwIwAg&url=http://railscasts.com/episodes/415-upgrading-to-rails-4?autoplay=true&ei=7zPZUc_ROpOL4gTq1oGYDw&usg=AFQjCNHTJ0ThpxbmxGxdlK5Caj3bi8n_cQ&sig2=AWSi4JCVyeeCgn5r_oD1xw&bvm=bv.48705608,d.bGE)

I have a model:

```
  class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :content, :presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 2 }
    validates :name, :presence => true,    :length => { :minimum => 2 }
    validates :value, :presence => true      
  end
```

After upgrading, in rails console I tried to create new test object

```
   Test.create(name: "asd", content:"asd", value: 5)
```

And got

```
  WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Achievement: name, content, value
  (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
=> #<Test id: nil, name: nil, content: nil, value: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Looks like I forgot to upgrade something. I tried to re-create rails application with overriding config and other rails files, but nothing changed.

I created new empty project and copied model files. It was working OK.

If I'll add

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false
```

to config/application.rb, my upgraded project will be working good. But it's not normal, because in empty rails4, this line was deleted.

What I forgot to upgrade or what must I do, to make upgraded project to work like empty created with rails4 and without config.activerecord ...?

### UPD

```
raw_params = {:name => "asdasd", :content=>"asdasdasd", :value=>5} 
=> {:name=>"asdasd", :content=>"asdasdasd", :value=>5} 
2.0.0dev :002 > params = ActionController::Parameters.new(raw_params)
=> {"name"=>"asdasd", "content"=>"asdasdasd", "value"=>5} 
2.0.0dev :003 >  test = Test.create(params.permit(:name, :value, :content))
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Achievement: name, value, content
 (0.2ms)  BEGIN
 (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
=> #<Test id: nil, name: nil, content: nil, value: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Comment: did you add the params in the controller?

Comment: @NickGinanto yes, but I don't use controller when I type Test.create in console.

Comment: maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15960121/rails-4-strong-parameters-failing-when-creating-instances-in-rails-console

Comment: @NickGinanto I looked at it.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16097970/1656464 it is useful, but I try to discover, why rails4 shows me rails3 errors.

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 4, `attr_accessible` is not used any more to do mass-assignment checking. Mass-assignment refers to the practice of creating or updating a Model object by passing a hash of values. When you do mass-assignment in Rails 4, you have to specify which parameters are allowed and which ones are not. This is due to security reasons.

Take a look at the repository for [strong_parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters), it contains a brief explanation of how mass-assignment security works in Rails 4. Especially look at **Use Outside Of Controllers**.

Comment: In my empty, created in rails4 app, this mass-assignment works good. And in app, that was upgraded from 3.2 to 4.0 it works not good.

Comment: I didn't see updated post. Thanks. I'll look at Use Outside of Controllers.

Comment: 2.0.0dev :001 > raw_parameters = { :name => "John", :content => "Dorrow" ,:value => 4 }

 => {:name=>"John", :content=>"Dorrow", :value=>4} 

2.0.0dev :002 > params = ActionController::Parameters.new(raw_parameters)
 => {"name"=>"John", "content"=>"Dorrow", "value"=>4} 
2.0.0dev :003 > params.class
 => ActionController::Parameters 
2.0.0dev :004 > a = Test.create(params.permit(:name, :content, :value))
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Achievement: name, content, value

oh lol.