# How do I generate a CSRF token from the Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf, refinerycms

I'm trying to make an authenticated post request, and I need the CSRF. When I log in, it isn't generating the `_csrf_token` for some reason:

```
2.0.0p247 :126 >   app.post '/community_members/login', {"refinery_user[login]"=>'chloe', 'refinery_user[password]'=>'test'}
 => 302
2.0.0p247 :127 > app.session
 => {"warden.user.refinery_user.key"=>[[56], "$2a$10$gr/rTcQfuXnes1Zml3qOPu"], "session_id"=>"f77d89cef9ff1710890f575b479bb690"}
```

I tried `app.session[:_csrf_token] ||= SecureRandom.base64(32)` before login, but it is always deleted. I also tried to get the login form first, but `_csrf_token` is still not set.

```
2.0.0p247 :133 >   app.get '/community_members/sign_in'
2.0.0p247 :134 > app.response # authenticity_token is burried in the raw HTML
2.0.0p247 :136 >   app.post '/community_members/login', {"refinery_user[login]"=>'chloe', 'refinery_user[password]'=>'test'}
2.0.0p247 :137 > app.session
 => {"warden.user.refinery_user.key"=>[[56], "$2a$10$gr/rTcQfuXnes1Zml3qOPu"], "session_id"=>"c2c564229e55b81ca788788558d7d11a"}
```

How do I manually generate the token to pass to the post request?

---

Oh ok, I think I need to submit the authenticity_token (that is set in the session after GETing the login form) to the login form, then it puts it in the session permanently! This worked:

> app.post '/community_members/login', {'authenticity_token'=>'GfT5GtcUmYQ927oNQmh2MR0NKQucGSx8mtMg3Ph9kXw=', "refinery_user[login]"=>'chloe', 'refinery_user[password]'=>'test'}

Here is a full example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23899701/148844

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I felt like using Nokogiri to parse the response was a little heavy so I wrote a simple regex to pull the authenticity token out of the response.

```
app.get  '/api_with_form'
authenticity_token = app.response.body.match(/<[^<]+authenticity_token[^>]+value="([^"]+)"[^>]+>/)[1]
```

I'm using this to log in

```
app.get  '/users/sign_in'
authenticity_token = app.response.body.match(/<[^<]+authenticity_token[^>]+value="([^"]+)"[^>]+>/)[1]
app.post '/users/sign_in', 'user[email]' => 'my_username', 'user[password]' => 'my_password', authenticity_token: authenticity_token
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this!

Answer (score 3):

Unless you load the page before you do `app.post`, there is no CSRF token generated to begin with. Manually generating a new one will not help because it won't match what is stored on the server, which is likely to be some `null` value.

You need to load the page, parse out the CSRF token, and then use that one.

Alternately, you can load the form, try to read the CSRF token out of `app.session[:_csrf_token]` and use that.

Comment: Even if I get the login form first, then post, `session[:_csrf_token]` is not set.

Comment: I had to submit the authenticity_token as part of the login!

Comment: @Chloe, I assume the accept means that you realized you have to load the login page first, and then get the token?

Answer (score 3):

I use these commands in rails console:

```
app_controller = ActionController::Base::ApplicationController.new
app_controller.request = ActionDispatch::Request.new({})
app_controller.send(:form_authenticity_token)
```