# How can I run a controller concern method from the console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

If I have a controller concern, for example:

```
module MyConcern

  def concern_method param
    puts param.inspect
  end

end
```

How can I test the method `concern_method` from the console?

Using methods described here:
[How do I call controller/view methods from the console in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151030/how-do-i-call-controller-view-methods-from-the-console-in-rails) I can access the application controller using:

```
controller = ActionController::Base::ApplicationController.new
```

... but then this throws an error:

```
controller.concern_method "hello world"

NoMethodError: undefined method `concern_method`  for #<ApplicationController:0x000001091fbad0>
```

Is the concern not added automatically to the controller when it is instantiated from the console?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this:

```
controller = ActionController::Base::ApplicationController.new
controller.extend(MyConcern)

controller.concern_method "hello world"
```

Answer (score 5):

To access a concern in the Rails 6 console, first run include in the console

```
include MyConcern
```

Then run your method in the console

```
concern_method
```