# Calling an ApplicationController method in a ruby file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, applicationcontroller

How can I call an application controller method inside of a Ruby file?  I can't use the traditional MVC architecture.

Thanks!

Comment: You mean you have a Rails application which has a method in the ApplicationController and you want to call a method on that class from a ruby file in the project but not part of the request cycle? Please clarify the question.

Comment: Could you show us your ApplicationController, describe what the method in question does, and the context in which the other ruby file is being ran?

Answer (score 0):

If the method is meant to be called from both the application controller and some other ruby file, then you need to move that method to another file, probably a Plain Old Ruby Object (PORO). Then, require that file from your controller and from whatever other file needs to use it.

It's a good idea to only have controller-related logic in controllers. Since you're calling this method from something besides a controller, it must not be strictly controller-related logic, so this is the perfect opportunity to move it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a method in the `ApplicationController` and you need to call it you can use a trick which is:

```
ApplicationController.new.#method_here
```

But you better move the method to a plugin and call it in the `ApplicationController` for a best practice.

More info here:

[How do I call controller/view methods from the console in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151030/how-do-i-call-controller-view-methods-from-the-console-in-rails)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9159853/2552259

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for your problem is to extract the method in question and put it in a module, like `lib/my_utils.rb`. Then you can require this file where ever you need it:

```
# lib/my_utils.rb
module MyUtils
  def the_method_you_were_talking_about(args)
    .. code ..
  end
end
```

Then:

```
# application_controller.rb
require 'lib/my_utils.rb'
MyUtils.the_method_you_were_talking_about("and any data you need to pass to it")
```

And then you'd do the same thing from your other ruby file.