# Abstracted way to find a method definition in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

Background:

I have been researching the Rails method number_to_currency, trying to find what units are available for the currency and how to pass them to the options block.  Going on both [APIDock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper/number_to_currency) and [Ruby on Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html), and searching the [Rails Repository](https://github.com/rails/rails), I have not found the actual method definition.  I have also tried to call the source_location method on number_to_currency but this returned an error.

Question:

I am looking for an abstracted way of finding any RoR method definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every ruby object has a method named `method`.
This `method`-method can be passed name and it will return a `method`-object containing information about the method with the given name.
This includes information about the `source_location` of the method as well.

Methods like `number_to_currency`are helper methods defined on the *view_context* object on which your views are exected on.

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151030/how-do-i-call-controller-view-methods-from-the-console-in-rails) on how to execute these on the console.

There you can then examine these methods like this:

```
irb(main):001:0> helper.number_to_currency 3.14
=> "3,14 €"
irb(main):002:0> helper.method(:number_to_currency)
=> #<Method: ActionView::Base(ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper)#number_to_currency>
irb(main):003:0> helper.method(:number_to_currency).source_location
=> ["/Users/at/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.1.5/lib/action_view/helpers/number_helper.rb", 107]
```