# Why can't I call an ActionView method from the Rails Console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to do a little testing of the number_to_currency method, but no matter how I try and call it in the console I'm out of luck it seems.

```
ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper::number_to_currency 12321334543.00
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `number_to_currency' for ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper:Module
```

This may qualify as a duplicate, I am not entirely sure. The other question is a lot broader in scope, and therefore has a lot more ways of getting things gone presented in the answers, and I also believe it may have some outdated answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I call controller/view methods from the console in Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151030/how-do-i-call-controller-view-methods-from-the-console-in-rails)

Comment: Theres also view_context {}, in that block the view methods are accesible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper is a module. Whenever you want to use it you should include it and all it's method could be used after that. So the first step is including ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper module:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
```

and then call the method you want:

```
number_to_currency 12321334543.00
```

Take a look at [Ruby modules tutorial](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html).

Edit:

Getting a console session bootstrapped with Rails’ helpers is also a pain, which helper can fix for you! You could also use it to play with building HTML tags, or any existing Rails helper that ActionView knows about (checkout [this blog post](https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3176-three-quick-rails-console-tips)).

```
helper.number_to_currency 12321334543.00
```

Answer (score 2):

try `helper.number_to_currency 12321334543.00`